# Envers Query - Don't Join with REVINFO Table

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am running a Hibernate AuditQuery to get revision info for an entity. With the second parameter as `false`, the result is joined with the REVINFO table:

```
AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(em);
AuditQuery query = reader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(Bar.class, false, true)
```

I don't want to join with the REVINFO table, but I do want the info on whether the revision was an ADD, MOD, or DEL. Is there a way to achieve this with an AuditQuery?

Getting the revision of entity with changes doesn't work either since the entity isn't marked with `@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)`

```
reader.createQuery().forRevisionOfEntityWithChanges(Bar.class, true)
```